# Constructing a HoTT proof term of 1≠0

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

As an exercise in HoTT basics, I am trying to construct a term that has the type $Id_{Nat}(S(O),O)\to\bot$. If this were a Coq proof, I'd be done after a single `inversion` on the premise, as the impossible identity would leave zero cases to consider. I guess I could do something similar here, but I'm not sure how. What would be an HoTT term that has the type?

Comment: A similar point is described in the book, I think regarding the Boolean type. You should have a look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the notation of the [HoTT Book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book) 
define the type family $P:\mathbb N\to\mathcal U$ by $P(0):\equiv\mathbf1$ and $P(\mathsf{succ}(n)):\equiv\mathbf0$, and let $p:0=\mathsf{succ}(0)$. Lemma 2.3.1 of the HoTT Book implies $p_*(*):\mathbf0$.