# Disequality in Type Theory

Tags: proof-theory, type-theory

Is it possible to prove $0 \neq 1$ in (non-univalent) Martin-Löf type theory, where $0$ and $1$ are natural numbers (defined using the usual inductive type $0 : \mathbb{N}$, $S : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$)?

Comment: @user122283 I used disequality because inequality risks confusion with *inequalities* (i.e. $x > y$), which are totally distinct. This term is used for example in the Homotopy Type Theory book, so it is not without precedent.

Comment: Whoops, my bad.

Comment: Univalence is not needed for [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376680/constructing-an-hott-proof-term-of-1%E2%89%A00).

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you! The HoTT in the title threw me off.